# OpenGL, GL_MODULATE and Multitexturing

Tags: opengl-es, texturing, multitexturing

I have successfully drawn a multi-textured polygon but unfortunately only the first pixel of the overlaying texture is being used across the entire texture area.

Here are the textures (GL_TEXTURE0 and GL_TEXTURE1):

[image: icon] [image: overlay]

The result is this:

[image: result]

Only the red pixel at the top is being used. I've tried with just a 1x1 blue pixel up the top and I get the same result with blue overlay.

My code:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

const CGPoint vertices[] = {
    ccp(0,0),
    ccp(100,0),
    ccp(0,100),
    ccp(100,100),
};

// This will flip the image for us as well
const CGPoint coordinates[] = {
    ccp(0,1),
    ccp(1,1),
    ccp(0,0),
    ccp(1,0),
};

// Config multitextures
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, icon.name);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE); 
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, coordinates);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, overlay.name);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, coordinates);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

GLubyte points = 4;

// Draw the square
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, points);

// Revert back
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

// glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); // breaks multitexturing
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

This is an OpenGL problem, but the iOS project is available here for those interested: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33811812/cocos2d/OpenGLTest.zip

**EDIT:**
From the Red Book:

> If you are multitexturing and you use glTexCoord*(), you are setting
>   the texture coordinates for the first texture unit. In other words,
>   using glTexCoord*() is equivalent to using glMultiTexCoord*
>   (GL_TEXTURE0,...)

Any hints as to how to pass an array of coordinates? OpenGL ES 1.1 doesn't support glBegin() etc.

Comment: It seems you are looking for [glClientActiveTexture](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glClientActiveTexture.xml).

Comment: Brilliant! Works, except that setting `glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);` after drawing causes it to fail again. I have other draw methods that I need to revert the states for. How can this be achieved?

Comment: I've also looked at `glVertexAttribPointer` but I have no clue how to use this to specify the coordinates for GL_TEXTURE1...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally! The solution was that I had to do three things:

- Use glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE*) for 0 and 1 before the glTexCoordPointer
- Use glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY) for each texture as well
- Revert back to glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0) to avoid conflicting with further draws

Here's the code that works:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

const CGPoint vertices[] = {
    ccp(0,0),
    ccp(100,0),
    ccp(0,100),
    ccp(100,100),
};

// This will flip the image for us as well
const CGPoint coordinates[] = {
    ccp(0,1),
    ccp(1,1),
    ccp(0,0),
    ccp(1,0),
};

// Config multitextures
glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, icon.name);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE); 
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, coordinates);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, overlay.name);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, coordinates);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

GLubyte points = 4;

// Draw the square
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, points);

// Revert back
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glClientActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

And the result:

[image: works]