# OpenGL conflicts when using both multi-texturing and GL_LINES

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have a scene in which I'd like to have some objects drawn using multi-texturing.  I'd also like to draw some objects using only gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINES...

However, whenever I add objects on-screen that have two textures applied, all objects that use GL_LINES or solid colors become faded.

I tried to put together a [simple demo](https://github.com/VoteBrian/MTDemo) where all objects use the same draw method (hopefully I didn't create more confusion while trying to simplify).

I handle the multi-texturing in Model.java, with the relevant section here:

```
// Texture 1
gl.glClientActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);
gl.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexture[0]);
gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_MODULATE);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mTexCoordBuffer1);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

// Texture 2
gl.glClientActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE1);
gl.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE1);
gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexture[1]);
gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_DECAL);
gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mTexCoordBuffer2);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note: Without the multi-textured object, outlines on triangles 1 and 4 are solid.  This is how I'd like the outlines to show.
[image: Outlines show when no objects on screen using multi-texturing]

Note: With the multi-textured object (triangle 3), outlines on triangles 1 and 4 are faded.
[image: Outlines look faded when I have a multi-textured object on screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116494/opengl-gl-modulate-and-multitexturing) that I had thought was unrelated.

I don't understand why, but I needed to call:

```
gl.glActiveTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE0);
```

after the Texture 2 block.